# Change a parent entity to a child entity in EntityFramework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following hierarchy models in Entity Framework 6.

ChildUser Inherits ParentUser. ParentUser has less fields than ChildUser and I am using the Table Per Hierarchy (TPH) inheritance structure of EF6.

In some situations the ParentUser is upgraded to ChildUser, so what is the best way to manage this?

```
// Naive way that doesn't work and doesn't take into account changing the discriminator
ParentUser parentUser = ctx.ParentUsers.Single(x => x.Id == 1);
ChildUser childUser = (ChildUser)parentUser;
childUser.ExtraField = "Some Value";
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Any pointers to the right directions are appreciated.

Comment: did you mean "Table per Hierarchy (TPH)" ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant table. I corrected the typo.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new ChildUser object, add the father params and add this new child to the DB

```
ChildUser childUser = new ChildUser();
ParentUser parentUser = ctx.ParentUsers.Single(x => x.Id == 1);

childUser.param1 = parentUser.param1;
....
childUser.ExtraField = "Some Value";
ctx.ChildUsers.Add(childUser); //Add the new child
ctx.ParentUsers.Remove(parentUser); //If you wanna remove the parent too
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: This is the straight forward way, but it means manually copying every single field or using something like AutoMapper and managing relationships with other entities (say there is a HistoryUser table).

Comment: @Adam Sure, but with EF it's the only way. Because: 1. You can't change the discriminator. 2. You can't change a CLR type at runtime, and that's what you're dealing with.